# How to connect Metamask to Rootstock networks?

Tags: javascript, metamask, rsk

I am building a DApp which connects to [Rootstock](https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/public-nodes/) Testnet and Mainnet via [MetaMask](https://docs.metamask.io/). Unfortunately, I didn't find Rootstock among the available networks out of the box in MetaMask.
​
[In this tutorial](https://developers.rsk.co/wallet/use/metamask/) I found the information on how to manually add Rootstock networks to MetaMask, however I don't want to bother users of my DApp by copying and pasting this information into MetaMask.
​
Is there a way to programmatically add this network config to Metamask and then immediately switch to that network, after a user initiates a wallet connection somewhere in this place:
​

```js
document
  .getElementById('connect-to-metamask-button')
  .addEventListener('click', async () => {
    await window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
    });
    // switch to the Rootstock network
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in addition to Petr's answer;

In summary, yes you can,
by using `wallet_addEthereumChain` and `wallet_switchEthereumChain`.
Details below.
​
Adding a new network is described [here in the Metamask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#wallet-addethereumchain).
​
To add the Rootstock networks to Metamask, first Create network configuration objects:
​
For the **Rootstock Testnet**:
​

```js
const rskTestnet = {
  chainName: 'Rootstock Testnet',
  chainId: '0x1f', // hex 31
  rpcUrls: ['https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co'],
  blockExplorerUrls: ['https://explorer.testnet.rsk.co/'],
  nativeCurrency: {
    symbol: 'tRBTC',
    decimals: 18,
  },
};
```

​
For the **Rootstock Mainnet**:
​

```js
const rskMainnet = {
  chainName: 'Rootstock Mainnet',
  chainId: '0x1e', // hex 30
  rpcUrls: ['https://public-node.rsk.co'],
  blockExplorerUrls: ['https://explorer.rsk.co/'],
  nativeCurrency: {
    symbol: 'RBTC',
    decimals: 18,
  },
};
```

​
When the user starts the DApp,
the first thing to do is to attempt to
switch to the target network
using `wallet_switchEthereumChain`.
Assuming you intend this to be the Rootstock Testnet:
​

```js
await window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
    params: [{ chainId: rskTestnet.chainId }],
});
```

​
However if the network you are trying to switch has yet to be added to Metamask (your case),
it will throw an error with a code `4902`, which you need to catch in a `try-catch` block.
​
When this happens, you have detected that
the user does not have this network configured in Metamask.
If this is the case, use `wallet_addEthereumChain` to add its config.
​

```js
await window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
    params: [rskTestnet],
});
```

​
Thus, the `switchToRskNetwork` function,
which you may want to call from the desired place in your DApp,
could look like this:
​

```js
async function switchToNetwork(network) {
  try {
    // switching to a network
    await window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
      params: [{ chainId: network.chainId }],
    });
    // catching the error 4902
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 4902) {
      // adding a new chain to Metamask
      await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
        params: [network],
      });
    }
  }
}
```

​
You should call this function either when
your DApp initialises
(e.g. adjacent to `eth_requestAccounts` in your example code),
or upon selection of the network by the user.
To do so, pass in the network configuration object:
​

```js
await switchToNetwork(rskTestnet)
```

Comment: Great! Awesome explanation Owans.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [wallet_addEthereumChain](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#wallet-addethereumchain) method ([EIP-3085](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3085)).

```
const error = await ethereum.request({
    method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
    params: [{
        chainId: "0x1E", // decimal 30
        chainName: "RSK Mainnet",
        nativeCurrency: {
            decimals: 18,
            symbol: "RBTC"
        },
        rpcUrls: [
            "https://public-node.rsk.co"
        ],
        blockExplorerUrls: [
            "https://explorer.rsk.co/"
        ]
    }]
});
```